# dataset count rows

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, count, dataset, row

I want to get the rows count of the `DataSet`, but the code here throws an exception

```
Dim con As New SqlConnection("server=localhost;database=MSDSS;Integrated Security=True")
Dim i As Integer
con.Open()
Dim qstr As String = "Select * From SJournal"
Dim sqladp As New SqlDataAdapter(qstr, con)
Dim dt As New DataSet

sqladp.Fill(dt, "SJ")
Dim j As Integer = dt.Tables("SJ").Rows.Count
For i = 0 To j Step 1
    Dim rowname As String = dt.Tables("SJ").Rows(i)("JournalName")
Next
```

here is how I Calculate the string similarity

```
Dim Kq As Double = 2
Dim Kr As Double = 1
Dim Ks As Double = 1
Dim ss() As Char = rowname.ToCharArray()
Dim st() As Char = journalname.ToCharArray()
Dim q As Integer = ss.Intersect(st).Count()
Dim s As Integer = ss.Length - q
Dim r As Integer = st.Length - q
Dim total As Double = (Kq * q) / (Kq * q + Kr * r + Ks * s)
```

Please give me solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Datatable` works like an array (in some way, when you use it on a for), and the index numeration of arrays goes from 0 to N-1

Considering N is the number of rows, you should modify this

```
Dim j As Integer = dt.Tables("SJ").Rows.Count
```

to

```
Dim j As Integer = dt.Tables("SJ").Rows.Count -1
```

So, if got 3 `rows`, the for cycle will go from 0 to 2

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that your for loop

```
For i = 0 To j Step 1
    Dim rowname As String = dt.Tables("SJ").Rows(i)("JournalName")
Next
```

should have j-1 as the upper bound, ie.

```
For i = 0 To j-1 Step 1
    Dim rowname As String = dt.Tables("SJ").Rows(i)("JournalName")
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You no need to open the connection explicitly if you are using dataadapter.

For more reference please visit:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1663393.aspx/1